# How long does a spell last in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, time

I didn't find this question or a related answer to my question.

Some spells like "Avada Kedavra" are spells that are intended to do one thing, the conjurer focuses on that spell and when they stop focusing, or the blast doesn't hit it's target, or the wizard dies, the spell ends.

A spell that opens a locked door for is another example, it either fails immediately or the door unlocks, either way the spell is over.

However, what about spells like the charming spells Harry, Hermione, and Ron used to conceal themselves?

They would get to a camp site, one of them would walk around the perimeter of the camp site and cast spells to conceal their location. Does the spell last in perpetuity? Does it only last while the conjurer is focusing on it? Does it last until it is dispelled by a counter spell? Does it just run out eventually?

I don'think the conjurer has to focus on it. It always appeared in the books and the movie that once these spells are cast the conjurer doesn't think about it again.

The charm spells are just an example. A love spell would fall into the same category as well. I believe the love spell Voldemorts mom put on his dad lasted until her mom released it and she didn't have to focus on it. There are many other examples of these types of spells as well.

You might want to consider Lily Potter's spell on the fish she gave to the professor as a gift in your answer. I believe it lasted until she died.

I don't know if each spell has a distinct amount of time that it lasts or if spells of this category follow a general rule.

Author's notes, interviews, etc. are welcome.

Comment: We know the magic associated with most invisibility cloaks wear out over time.  We know Dumbledore spell immobilizing Harry terminated at the end of Half-Blood Prince.

Comment: @Zoredache I was going to mention Dumbledore. You beat me by moments:) On the other hand, there are spells that do seem to last in perpetuity (Marauder's Map, enchantment on the Hogwarts Castle [unless those get 'renewed']). It seems like each enchantment has a different 'expiration date', as well as the 'strength' of the spell changing its' longevity (i.e. Harry's invisibility cloak vs. every other one).

Comment: Which makes me think of another question (maybe I'll ask it): was Harry's invisibility cloak made of a different spell/material that it lasted indefinitely, or was it simply a stronger wizard who initially cast the spell?

Comment: @Salmononius2, it's a portion of Death's cloak of course :P

Comment: Dumbledore’s additional spells on Privet Drive lasted 16 years, including a few months after Dumbledore himself had died. There are other similar cases: the Mirror of Erised seems like it's kept its spells functioning possibly for centuries; the same goes for most of the objects that are ‘cleaned’ out from Grimmauld Place in August 1995 (though more curses than spells); and of course Harry's cloak and wands in general. Good question!

Comment: Voldemort's mother did not put a love *spell* on her husband, she [gave him a love *potion*](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Merope_Gaunt#Marriage) (assuming Dumbledore is right).  One imagines she simply stopped dosing him.

Comment: I've been tempted to ask this, but it seems to be that they're mostly fit to purpose. I think someone says that their protective charms need to be renewed/refreshed and I think a lot of spells just wear off, but that's not too difficult to sort out. I also think enchanted objects last much longer, eg the flying car, the mirror mentioned and the map mentioned. The cloaks that wear out seem to be examples of poor quality products compared to good quality in my opinion.

Comment: Related question, I don’t *think* it’s a dupe: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85460/3567

Comment: @alexwlchan I looked at that when I considered asking this myself but I think that is a more specific question.